# Load service for interface only where there is no other service

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my application I have interface with default implementation that is service:

```
public interface MessageGenerator {
    Message getMessage();
}

@Service
public class PropertiesMessageGenerator implements MessageGenerator {
    @Override
    public Message getMessage() {
        return doSmth();
    }
}
```

This service is loaded by spring boots `#ComponentScan` and everything works fine until I've added new implementation with `@Profile`

```
@Service
@Profile("p1")
public class ProfileMessageGenerator implements MessageGenerator {
    @Override
    public Message getMessage() {
        return doSmthWithProfile();
    }
}
```

How can I stop loading into DI service `PropertiesMessageGenerator` when `ProfileMessageGenerator` is in context?

PS
I cannot use `@Profile("default")` on `MultipleMessages`, because I've got more profiles that I load at one time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use component scanning you could define and pick the bean using `@Qualifier`

If you want to maintain using component scanning use the `@Conditional` annotation.

Create your own implementation of 'org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition.class' and pass this to the annotation.

This could read a property to define when it returns true which could be set when what you want is in the context.

`@ConditionalOnMissingBean(MessageGenerator.class)` can be used if you do not want to implement your own Condition.

Or just annotate ProfileMessageGenerator with `@Primary`.

Comment: ```@ConditionalOnMissingBean(MessageGenerator.class)``` did the work. Thanks

Comment: This dose not work for me. 
I encountered the same issue as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996440/how-to-create-a-default-overridable-component-in-spring

Could you please elaborate? @MAGx2

Answer (score 4):

A bit late to the party, but might help future visitors:

I've got it working in Spring Boot 2.5.1 by configuring my service like this:

```
@Service
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(value = BaseService.class, ignored = DefaultService.class)
public class DefaultService implements BaseService {
    ...
}
```

Without the `ignored` field in the annotation, the condition will match `DefaultService` and thus not instantiate it. That behavior is a bit strange, but excluding itself from the condition makes it work. With this, I can create an additional implementation of `BaseService` that is just annotated with `@Service` and instead it will not instantiate `DefaultService` but the other implementation.