# How to create a default overridable Component in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to create a `Component` that will be `Autowired` unless the user creates a different implementation.
I used the following code to try and isolate the problem:

The interface:

```
public interface A {...}
```

The implementation:

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(A.class)
public class AImpl implements A {...}
```

The usage code:

```
public class AUsage {
    @Autowired
    private A a;
}
```

In this example, I don't get `AImpl` autowired into `AUsage`.
If I implement `A` in another class without the `ConditionalOnMissingBean` it works.

Comment: Of course, for this to work, `AUsage` must also be a Spring bean. In your example above it doesn't have a `@Component` annotation. Did you just forget to copy & paste that into your question? If `AImpl` is not injected, then it is most likely in a package that is not component scanned. Make sure that the package that contains `AImpl` is included in component scanning.

Comment: `If I implement A in another class without the ConditionalOnMissingBean it works.` and what if you remove _ConditionalOnMissingBean_ annotation from the code above? If bean still not been autowired - looks like the problem is related to smth described by @Jesper

Comment: AUsage has a `@Component` annotation, but I hid it to isolate the problem.

Comment: @bsiamionau it also works if I remove the `ConditionalOnMissingBean`

Comment: I think I found a solution, or at least a workaround. I'll post it tomorrow hopefully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried copying existing uses of `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` from the internet and noticed that they all reference a `@Bean` method.

Indeed, when I added this code to AUsage:

```
public class AUsage {
    @Autowired
    private A a;

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public A createA() {
        return new AImpl();
    }
}
```

and removed the annotations from AImpl:

```
public class AImpl implements A {...}
```

everything works as expected.

I'd be pleased to get an explanation to this, if anyone knows.

Comment: I'm quite positive you'll find the explanation for the observed behavior (that I also faced) in these two threads:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1625

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17655